# How do I remove #! from URL

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to change

```
http://domain.co.uk/#!/pagename
```

to

```
http://domain.co.uk/pagename
```

I was thinking of going URL re-write and then realised that as it is a single page website this will not work, so I am stuck!

Is there a way to do it given existing code-base (a quick javascript function?) or is it just something I have to live with?

! am guessing the latter (well could change to domain.co.uk#pagename I suppose) but am happy to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics are simple enough:

```
if (location.hash && (location.hash.substr(1,1) === "!")) {
    location.replace(location.toString().replace('#!', "/"));
};
```

You just need to make sure that the new URLs work first.

That means:

1. Updating the client side code to use pushState and friends (so you stop generating hashbang URIs)
2. Updating the server side code so it can deliver each page of the site in the correct state without depending on the client side code (so that (a) any page can load quickly and efficiently and (b) JavaScript becomes a performance boosting bonus instead of a search engine hating dependancy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I am not smart enough to implement this unfortunately as whenever I try the re-write as above my server treats it as a separate page and throws a 404 - for a single page site I have realised there is no way around a # - that is unless I have mis-understood the above??!!??

Comment: It *is* a separate page. See point 2 in the list of prerequisites listed in the answer. Singe page sites are, generally, an awful idea (which is why Twitter, for example, had horrible performance problems and ran away from their single page implementation).

Comment: Thanks for guidance - I see point 2 - but simply don't get it - can you point me in the right direction - I don't get how to get my server to serve 1 page but then go to the correct sub-section on that page based on the second parameter in the URL without it treating it like a different page - I presume this is a URL re-write at this stage? Sorry if I am just not following but I am obviously being a ickle bit thick!

Comment: There is no URL rewriting involved. If you just want to link to a subsection of a page, then that would be a URL with a `#` and no `!`. If you want to link to the page in the state it is in after the DOM has been manipulated with JS, then you figure out the HTML that would give the same effect as starting with the original HTML and running the JS, then you serve that HTML to the client instead.

Comment: Thanks - I think I got it now so marking as accepted - may be asking another question in a bit (seperate question to this one!) but we will see :-P